# PHP Add Time, not working in US date format

Tags: php, server-side

I'm English but working for an American client, he wants the time displaying plus an offset.

Why does this work:

```
$date = date('d-m-Y H:i');
$timeToAdd = strtotime(date("d-m-Y H:i", strtotime($date)) . " + 8 hour");
$newDate = date('d-m-Y H:i', $timeToAdd);
echo 'Current Time: ' . $date . '<br/>Time + 8 Hours: ' . $newDate;
```

Which produces:

Current Time: 17-06-2012 08:53
Time + 8 Hours: 17-06-2012 16:53

and this wont (month and day switched):

```
$date = date('m-d-Y H:i');
$timeToAdd = strtotime(date("m-d-Y H:i", strtotime($date)) . " + 8 hour");
$newDate = date('m-d-Y H:i', $timeToAdd);
echo 'Current Time: ' . $date . '<br/>Time + 8 Hours: ' . $newDate;
```

which produces:

Current Time: 06-17-2012 08:56
Time + 8 Hours: 12-31-1969 16:00

1969

?!

Comment: Because the month and day are switched, I'd guess. (Or is that your question?)

Comment: yeh that's the question. Why is it not working in the US way, but is in the UK way?

Comment: So you were expecting it not to work, and changed it prematurely? :|

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the Notes section in [the documentation for `strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime):

> #### Note:
>
> Dates in the `m/d/y` or `d-m-y` formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (`/`), then the American `m/d/y` is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (`-`) or a dot (`.`), then the European `d-m-y` format
>   is assumed.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (`YYYY-MM-DD`)
>   dates or `DateTime::createFromFormat()` when possible.

You're using a `-` as a separator, so it's assuming `d-m-y`.